# Control inheritance and blendability

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I created a custom control which inherits from Window.  The goal is to make a reusable window for all the small apps I'll program in my company, and not having to redo the header/footer/base styles... each time.

So here is what I did.

The class:

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
    public bool ShowHeader
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowHeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowHeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowHeader.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowHeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowHeader", typeof(bool), typeof(MyWindow), new PropertyMetadata(true));


    public string HeaderText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeaderText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(MyWindow), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public MyWindow()
    {
        this.Template = FindResource("MyWindowTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
    }
}
```

The template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyWindowTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type me:MyWindow}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <DockPanel>
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="Images/logo.gif" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{TemplateBinding HeaderText}" />
            </Grid>

            <ContentPresenter />

        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Those 2 things are in a class library.

In my app, I have set this.

app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="TestInheritance.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ClassLibrary1;component/MyStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and my MainWindow.xaml is:

```
<uc:MyWindow x:Class="TestInheritance.MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:ClassLibrary1;assembly=ClassLibrary1"
             Title="MainWindow"
             Width="525"
             Height="350"
             HeaderText="Test1234"
             ShowHeader="True">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="test text" />
    </Grid>
</uc:MyWindow>
```

All of this works as intended in execution, but in the designer, I don't see the header (no matter the value I set for ShowHeader), neither the HeaderText.

What should I do to make all this "blendable", and see the header in the designer ?

## EDIT

I tried moving the `ControlTemplate` in a style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type me:MyWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type me:MyWindow}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="Images/logo.gif" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{TemplateBinding HeaderText}" />
                        </Grid>

                        <ContentPresenter />

                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and use this

```
StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(FindResource(typeof(MyWindow))));
```

in Mywindow's constructor.
So now, I have the opposite, I see the header in design mode, but not in the application anymore...

## EDIT2

I moved the style in `Themes\Generic.xaml` and added `[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]` in the Assemblyinfo.cs of my class library.

I also added a static constructor to my class like this:

```
static MyWindow()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyWindow)));
}
```

and it still doesn't work.

So now my solution structure is the following: (non-relevant parts omitted)

### Solution

- ClassLibrary1

  - Properties

    - AssemblyInfo.cs
  - Themes

    - Generic.xaml
  - MyWindow.cs

---

- TestInheritance (the wpf app)

  - App.xaml
  - MainWindow.xaml

## Edit3

Here is the link to my code: https://github.com/MerlinDuChaos/TestInheritance/

Comment: Can you try to debug your control with this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514636(v=vs.90).aspx just to see if constructor will be called at all

Comment: This seems hard to implement (is the adorner mandatory ?  I don't understand how to apply this in my own control).  However, I tried some things in the constructor, like changing the background color, or the content, and nothing changed.  So I guess the constructor is not called.

Comment: Then you have to work with xaml. Like this: MyWindow Template={StaticResource MyWindowTemplate}

Comment: I tried with a style, can you read my edit, to see if it's what you meant ?

Comment: Leave x:Key="MyWindowTemplate" and FindResource away just use FrameworkPropertyMetadata((typeof(MyWindow)))...

Comment: (I added the style in my edit)  I tried, but if I use the typeof, i get an exception at runtime, saying `Default value type does not match type of property 'Style'.`

Comment: Sorry i ment something else.. please read my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default style in static constructor like this

```
static MyWindow()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyWindow)));
}
```

Also dont forget to set this stupid little property:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type me:MyWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
```

Try it out now

**EDIT:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    //public App()
    //{
    //    InitializeComponent();

    //    FrameworkElement.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
    //    {
    //        DefaultValue = FindResource(typeof(Window))
    //    });
    //}
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

To force designer apply your custom window style you shall copy paste this inside app xaml.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:/ClassLibrary1;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I did this, and it ¸didn't work.  I moved my style in a generic.xaml file, placed in a Themes folder.  I also added `[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]` in my assembly.info, and it doesn't work either.  I'll update my question with these information.

Comment: I tried but I didn't work.  I submitted my code on GitHb, here is the link: https://github.com/MerlinDuChaos/TestInheritance/  thanks for your help !

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just tried it, but unfortunatly it didn't work either.  What this flag did to my window is remove the title bar, but I still don't see my header in the designer.  And setting the DefaultStyleKeyProperty doesn't display the header in execution mode neither :-/

Comment: I'm so sorry, but it still doesn't work (and worse now, when I run the app, I only have a black window without any content). I updated the git repository with the latest version of the code.

Comment: You have to set the background color to white. I forgot to tell you I am sorry. Its a must for every window else window stays transparent and GPU draws transparent as black. I had to do that too with your custom window in your solution when I downloaded it first time. Then everything shall work you my friend. I hope now we solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  I've set the background to white, and I can see the header in execution mode, but not yet in designer mode :-(  Is it working for you with the code I provided in Github ?

Comment: Window is one of the root controls in wpf (there are few of there for example a Page is one too) and so it's not like other content controls. The simple answer to your question is designer is not loading the style of your custom window. Which is good so. Designer always shows the default window. However you can force Designer to try seek for your custom window style. Designer will then find the style but not everything will but completely applied. Try set background color of your window to pink or something and you will notice that designer will find the style but you will not have your title

Comment: See my edit.. If all this solves your issues right now please mark your question as answered.

Comment: Yes, it works with your edit, both in design and execution modes.  thanks a lot for your help and patience !

Comment: I was too quick...  Ok, this works now, and the header is shown in design mode, but if I set the property `ShowHeader` to false, if doesn't hide (I updated the code to map this property in the templace).  Do you have an idea why ?  The designer seems to only read the default value of the dependency property, and not change it when set in the xaml...

Comment: Mhhhh ok, thanks for the answer.  I tried with Blend, and it's the same.